# Parse file up to a certain content in Python

Tags: python, file, tuples

I have a file that contains names and numbers.

Ex:

```
25
27
90
Robert
34
Liam
```

What I want to do is to add all the numbers before the name and store them along with the name they are assigned to. I wanted to make it a little like a tuple list. For example for the name Robert, you should get (142, Robert). Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share any code you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would edit your question to better explain your input data as you have to me, but I was able to get your expected output with the following:

file.txt

```
25
27
90
Robert
34
Liam
```

main.py

```
with open('/path/to/some/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.read().split()]

res = []
tot = 0
for line in lines:
    if line.isdecimal():
        tot += int(line)
    else:
        res.append((tot, line))
        tot = 0

print(res)
```

outputs:

```
[(142, 'Robert'), (34, 'Liam')]
```

Comment: They are all in a new line

Comment: 25 (enter) 27 (enter) 90 (enter) Robert. But this is really useful. Perhaps I can make something out of it. Thank's.

Comment: @AlexJB please see my edit--should work with your given data

Comment: Thank you! I was frying my brains with this. I'm not too used to work with files yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
f = open('abc.txt', 'r')

content = f.readline()

before_nums = content.split('Robert')
individuals = before_nums[0].split()

print(int(individuals[0]) + int(individuals[1]) + int(individuals[2]))
```

Answer (score -1):

this piece of code is working. It's better to try first instead of asking.

```
s = "25 27 90 Robert 34 Liam".split()
final = []
sum = 0
for _ in s:
    if _.isdecimal():
        sum += int(_)
    else:
        final.append(str(sum) + ", " + _  )
        sum = 0
print(final)
```